# R: Inserting a picture into faceted ggplot using annotation_custom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've gotten stuck trying to insert a png into ggplot that is faceted.  I've followed http://es.codeover.org/questions/32807665/removing-one-tablegrob-when-applied-to-a-box-plot-with-a-facet-wrap and can get it to work with sample datasets but not with my dataset.

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(scales)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(car)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)
library(grid)
library(png)


annotation_custom2 <- 
      function (grob, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, data) 
      {
        layer(data = data, stat = StatIdentity, position = PositionIdentity, 
              geom = ggplot2:::GeomCustomAnn, inherit.aes = TRUE, params = list(grob = grob,xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))
      }
```

This works:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_wrap(~ cyl)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
g1 <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=FALSE)
g <- grobTree(grobTree(g1, vp=viewport(x=unit(0,"npc"), y=unit(0,"npc"))))
p + annotation_custom2(g, data=data.frame(cyl=8))
```

My data gives an error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'genotypes' not found

```
p <- ggplot(FCStd, aes(x = genotypes, y = StandTotal, colour = type)) + geom_point(size = 3.5) +  facet_wrap(~type, scales = "free_x")  
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
    g1 <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=FALSE)
    g <- grobTree(grobTree(g1, vp=viewport(x=unit(0,"npc") + 0.5*sum(tg$widths), y=unit(0,"npc") + 0.5*sum(tg$heights))))
p + annotation_custom2(g1, data = data.frame(type == "invasive"))

dput(FCStd)
structure(list(genotypes = structure(c(29L, 27L, 19L, 20L, 18L, 
21L, 28L, 30L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 24L, 4L, 23L, 6L, 8L, 22L, 17L, 
12L, 31L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 26L, 25L, 16L, 1L, 13L, 10L, 15L, 32L
), .Label = c("Afghanistan PI250782", "Algeria W65435", "Australia PI197336", 
"Australia W65527", "Brazil PI404356", "Chile PI368930", "Chile PI368939", 
"Chile PI368940", "Chile PI368959", "CM NS ", "CM S ", "GIL NS ", 
"Greece W65319", "Hungary W65565", "Iran PI227025", "Malta W65375", 
"Mt Wilson-2", "Mt. Wilson-4", "NM58-12", "NM58-13", "NM58-35", 
"Peru PI308523", "Rivercrest-1", "Rivercrest-11", "Spain W65325", 
"Spain W65390", "St. Augustine-11", "St. Augustine-14", "St. Augustine-3", 
"Starlight", "Turkmenistan W62449", "Uzbekistan W68297"), class = "factor"), 
    type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("invasive", "native"
    ), class = "factor"), StandTotal = c(1, 1, 1, 0.2, 0.75, 
    0.5, 1.272727273, 0.666666667, 0.666666667, 0, 1.285714286, 
    1, 1, 1, 0.4, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.666666667, 1.259259259, 1.375, 
    1, 1.142857143, 1.166666667, 1.5, 1.5, 1.8, 1, 0.75, 0, 1, 
    1), LatGroup4 = c(4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
    7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L), LatGroup13 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L), LatGroupNI = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L), .Label = c("I", "N", "NI"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("genotypes", 
"type", "StandTotal", "LatGroup4", "LatGroup13", "LatGroupNI"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L))
```

Comment: `data = data.frame(type == "invasive")` in the annotation layer doesn't make sense to me

Comment: what's tg$widths and tg$heights?

Comment: data = data.frame(type == "invasive") : This is where I think the problem is. If I do ="invasive" I get the same error. If I do = invasive, I get object invasive not found. If I do == invasive, I get object type not found.

Comment: tg is from the original code that I used. It didn't give me an error when I was using my code so I forgot to remove it. I'm going to edit it out of the code because I got an error just now and I don't think it makes a difference.